# Service fails to run on Kubernetes due to authentication issue with NPM

Tags: npm, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm attempting to deploy a service to the google cloud kubernetes platform. All other services are running fine, but this one fails to load up due to an authentication error. I'm not sure what the issue is.

This is the error:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="GitHub Package Registry"
```

I've assured of the following:

- .npmrc file with the correct registry.
- Cloudbuild.yaml present.
- Dockerfile present.

The configuration is pretty much the same as the other services that do work.

Edit: Also, there is an authentication token associated with this build from a base Docker image that's linked in the dockerfile.

Comment: Can you make sure your `.npmrc` file points to github package registry with following format: `registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/<OWNER>` and you are using GITHUB_TOKEN?

Comment: Good pointer - although I've fixed the issue with another solution. The Github token was being retrieved from a Docker base image so that was being handled there.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue:

```
FROM gcr.io/xxxxx

# Copy in the project files
COPY . .

# Clean
USER root
RUN rm -fr node_modules

USER pptruser

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN npm install && \
    npm cache clean --force

EXPOSE 4000

# Running the app
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

The "pptruser" was not present but after comparing some other dockerfiles from other services I realized its use was essential.